# applying ajax in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I wanted to apply ajax in the laravel 4.2.i wanted to redirect to a page without reloading it.i'm have tried using the `window.loaction.href` and `window.loaction.assign` but it's not working. here are my files

**Route.php**

```
        //login+logout+auth
    Route::get('login','authenticationController@create')->before('guest');
    Route::get('logout','authenticationController@destroy');
    Route::get('create_user_view',array('as'=>'create_user','uses'=>'authenticationController@create_user'));
    Route::post('create_user_store',array('as'=>'store_user','uses'=>'authenticationController@store_user'));

Route::resource('authentication','authenticationController');
```

**controller.php**

```
public function store()
{
    // return Response::json(array('msg'=>'true'),200);exit;    
    $input=Input::all();
    $user=User::where('email',$input['email'])->pluck('id');

    $user_priviledge=Priviledge::where('user_id', $user)->pluck('user_authority');
    //var_dump($user_priviledge);die;

    if($user_priviledge==1)
    {   
        $attempt=Auth::attempt([
        'email'=>$input['email'],
        'password'=>$input['password']

    ]);
        //var_dump($input['password']);die;
        //var_dump($attempt);exit;
        if($attempt)
        {   

            return 'true';
        }else{
            return Redirect::intended('login');
            }
    }else{
        return Redirect::intended('login')->with('message', 'User Disabled');;
    }
}
```

**balde**

```
    @extends('app')

@section('content')
<!--login form-->
<div class="login">
    {{Form::open(array('url'=>route('authentication.store')))}}
    <div>
        <h2>Sign in to your account</h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th class="table">{{ Form::text('email', Input::old('E-mail'),  array('id'=>'email','placeholder'=>'E-Mail','class'=>'placeholder')) }}</th>
                <th>{{$errors->first('email')}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="table">{{ Form::password('password', array('id'=>'password','placeholder'=>'Your Password','class'=>'placeholder')) }}</th>
                <th class="table">{{$errors->first('password')}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <div>
                    <th class="table">{{Form::button('Login',array('class' => 'btn-login','onclick'=>'myfunc()'))}}</th><!--login button code-->
                </div>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="table"><!--reset button code-->
                    <div class="reset">
                        <a href="">I can't access my account</a>
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="table"><!--create button code-->
                    <div class="create-account">
                        <a href="{{route('create_user')}}">Create Account</a>
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>  
</div>
<script>
    function myfunc(){

        var email =document.getElementById("email").value;
        var password =document.getElementById("password").value;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                //alert("hello");
                // var data = xmlhttp.responseText;

                // console.log(xmlhttp.respons?eText);
                var text = Json.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                console.log(text);
                if(xmlhttp.responseText =='true'){

                    window.location.assign('http://localhost/votting-system/public/home');
                    //alert("hello");
                }
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST",'http://localhost/votting-system/public/authentication',true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("email=" +email+ "&password=" +password);
    }
</script>
@stop
```

Now the problem is when i clicked the submit button it should have redirected to a page where the home page exist but when i clicked the login button the it does nothing then when i reload the page it shows the home page.that means its being logged in but the page is not getting redirected to the home page without reloading.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to try `href` property of `location` object

```
window.location.href='http://localhost/votting-system/public/home';
```

Comment: Sorry i tried that too but its not working .like i click the login button the nothing happened then i just reloaded the page it showed the home page.@identity Unknown

Comment: Did you check the console for any errors? It would be probably a  JS Error

Comment: no errors ...but im using the right way right? it should have been worked right? @Identity Unknown

Comment: wait now its working but its getting the page reloaded ..is there any way to do so without reloading the page?@Identity Unknown

Comment: sorry...dint get you, what you exactly mean by getting reloaded?

Comment: as in ajax the page doesnt get refreshed it just change the contents like that i wanted to redirect the page to home page without refreshing the page and it will change the url and load the contents of the home page.@Identity Unkn0wn

Comment: When you are redirecting to a page, is that page getting refreshed?

Comment: May be the page to which it is redirected must be containing some reload script or from the backend may be from constructor or something, you are reloading it

Comment: Here is the full source code can you please look into it? [the github link](https://github.com/shihab-92/votting-system)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82282/discussion-between-ethereal-soul-and-identity-unkn0wn).